# Official pod for Parse?

Tags: parse-platform

Is there any official pod of Parse SDK that works on iOS?

I found "Parse" SDK on Cocoapods but couldn't find any pod's descriptions at Parse.com.

I also found the question article below.
At the comment, the staff of Parse said 2 years ago 
that "We'd like to have official CocoaPods support soon." 
https://parse.com/questions/official-support-for-cocoapods-library-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've been able to infer, the Parse podspec at https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/Parse ([v1.5.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/Parse/1.5.0/Parse.podspec.json) at time of writing) is the *most* official. The committer appears to work for Parse/Facebook, so that's the best endorsement I've seen so far.